# React Native - Expo notification Scheduling

Tags: react-native, expo

Im building a react native App using expo. Im able to send notifications daily like so

```js
Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
  content: {
    title: "Reminder",
    body: "lorem ipsum",
  },
  trigger: {
    hour: 12,
    minute: 30,
    repeats: true,
  },
});
```

My goal is to send a reminder to the user every day at the same time. I want to send a different reminder message each day say from a database or an array of messages, how do I go about doing that? been stuck for a while

Comment: Where will the database live? a web service? where will the array of messages come from, and how?

Comment: the database, would be cloud firestore, the array would come from the same file as the function

Answer (score 1):

This method to schedule notification does not allow specific code to run when the notification is fired. If you have the message you want to send for the next time, you can fetch that data the moment you schedule the notification. Otherwise, I think you should do that on your server-side application using [expo's push API](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/) with some kind of cron job.

Another alternative could be the [BackgroundFetch](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/) api, but you'll need to code some logic to re-schedule the task to fetch the data and send the notification.